# Can we give path for raster constructor in paper.js without <img> tag

Tags: canvas, paperjs

Is it possible to give an image path (url or local) for raster constructor in paper.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted below by the original author, creating a Raster from a URL works

Answer (score 0):

Ya..Cool , we can use image URL directly..

```
var imgUrl="http://www.myimgesource.com";
var raster=new Raster(imgUrl);
```

thanks,
suribabu